# Parsing Outlook Emails using Python

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to open emails from Outlook to extract certain text from the emails' body using Python. I have tried installing win32com.client, pywin32, imapclient, & msg-extractor but when I try to download, it says:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

I have tried this with both python 3 and python 2.7. After some research, it appears that python no longer supports MAPI as of Jan 2020 and I can't seem to find any way to open an Outlook email without using some form of MAPI.

I am relatively new to python so any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it will be helpful if you post your code and see where the problem is

Comment: This error is when I am trying to install pywin32 in my Linux terminal. I can't even start writing any code without installing it since the very first line would be importing pywin32, which will not install.

Comment: You can try this. https://www.codeforests.com/2020/06/04/python-to-read-email-from-outlook/ As an aside, this would be a lot easier if you are open to using a combination of Outlook + Excel + VBA. https://www.encodedna.com/excel/how-to-parse-outlook-emails-and-show-in-excel-worksheet-using-vba.htm ...or... https://www.howtoexcel.org/how-to-import-your-outlook-emails-into-excel-with-vba/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample using exchangelib in python

https://medium.com/@theamazingexposure/accessing-shared-mailbox-using-exchangelib-python-f020e71a96ab

Though it reads a shared mailbox and requirement/goal of the code is a bit different than yours but it should work for a regular personal mailbox.

Hope it helps!